# Add Button to Node View

Tags: 8, nodes, hooks

I want to add custom button on node page.

[image]

I tried with `hook_node_view` but it didn't show up.

like this:

```
function mymodule_node_view(array &$build, EntityInterface $entity, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {

$build['mybutton'] = [
  '#type'       => 'button',
  '#name'       => 'mybutton_name',
  '#value'      => t('Click Here'),
  '#attributes' => [ 'class' => 'button button--primary'],
  '#weight'     => -11,
];
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Here is the template

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Display Suite 2 column stacked template.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - outer_wrapper: outer wrapper element
 * - header_wrapper: wrapper element around header region
 * - left_wrapper: wrapper element around left region
 * - right_wrapper: wrapper element around right region
 * - footer_wrapper: wrapper element around footer region
 * - attributes: layout attributes
 * - header_attributes: attributes for header region
 * - left_attributes: attributes for left region
 * - right_attributes: attributes for right region
 * - footer_attributes: attributes for footer region
 * - header: content of header region
 * - left: content of left region
 * - right: content of right region
 * - footer: content of footer region
 */
#}

<{{ outer_wrapper }}{{ attributes.addClass('ds-2col-stacked', 'clearfix') }}>

  {{ title_suffix.contextual_links }}

  <{{ header_wrapper }}{{ header_attributes.addClass('group-header') }}>
    {{ header }}
  </{{ header_wrapper }}>

  <{{ left_wrapper }}{{ left_attributes.addClass('group-left') }}>
    {{ left }}
  </{{ left_wrapper }}>

  <{{ right_wrapper }}{{ right_attributes.addClass('group-right') }}>
    {{ right }}
  </{{ right_wrapper }}>

  <{{ footer_wrapper }}{{ footer_attributes.addClass('group-footer') }}>
    {{ footer }}
  </{{ footer_wrapper }}>

</{{ outer_wrapper }}>
```

Comment: And did you clear cache?

Comment: Yes, multiple times. The problem is this hooks runs and mybutton is added to build array but this button is not showing up when viewing node.

Comment: Your template  already render variable {{content}} or {{content.button}}?

Comment: I think so cause I didn't touch node template. I'm using default template.

Comment: I'm using display suite and it's template is not rendering {{content}}. is this the reason?

Comment: Ds use hook_entity_view_alter, this hook will run after hook_entity_views. You can using hook_entity_view_alter with your name module start with character after D (example e,g, h...) and copy your code to inside.

Comment: sorry I did not understand what you mean by `your name module start with character after D (example e,g, h...) ` ?

Comment: Because the same hook execute by order, default same hook will order by module name. You need a hook run after ds_entity_view_alter() so module name start with ...

Comment: I tried what you said but same results then disabled ds, only I can view my button. As it seems I need to add this button somehow on template file but don't know exactly how?

Comment: You need print it {{ mybutton }} in template twig

Comment: thanks I had to create custom ds layout.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried it out myself and for me it didn't work using your malformatted `#attributes` array. After I fixed it the following did work. `class` must provide another array.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view().
 */
function MYMODULE_node_view(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {

  $build['mybutton'] = [
    '#type'       => 'button',
    '#name'       => 'mybutton_name',
    '#value'      => t('Click Here'),
    '#attributes' => ['class' => ['button', 'button--primary']],
    '#weight'     => -11,
  ];
}
```

Comment: You are right but still not showing up, seems problem with display suite as @leymannx wrote